# Chained method calls doesn't work on original nor cloned element, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="condition_value_1" style="display: none" />    
<button id="showme">Make Select2</button>
<button id="clickme">Make Input</button>
```

Then take a look to the following jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var cond1 = $('#condition_value_1');
  var cloned_cond1 = cond1.clone();
  var cond1_select = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1" multiple="multiple"><option></option><option value="1">Opt1</option><option value="2">Opt2</option></select>';

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    cond1.removeAttr('style').replaceWith(cond1_select).select2({
      placeholder: 'Select choice'
    });

  });

  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    if ($('#condition_value_1').hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible')) {
      $("#condition_value_1").select2('destroy');
    }

    $('#condition_value_1').replaceWith(cloned_cond1).removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

You can try the code above **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/kknuuesq/4/)**.

Now as soon as you click on `#showme` you should remove the attr style, replace the original element with the given one and turn it into a Select2, the last part isn't working.

In the other side if you click on `#clickme` you should destroy the previous Select2 replace the `#condition_value_1` with the cloned element and remove the attr style because the cloned has that attribute but this is not working either.

The idea is to switch between elements and turn on/off properties on demand.

Maybe I am missing something here but I am not sure what. Could any help me here?

Comment: removing attribute doesn't update the property ..... instead use `show()` method,

Comment: `cond1.replaceWith(cloned_cond1);
cond1.removeAttr('style');` is backwards, is it not? `cloned_cond1.removeAttr('style'); cond1.replaceWith(cloned_cond1);`

Comment: @PranavCBalan that doesn't work either

Comment: @MisterPositive is showing the cloned element to you? because isn't working for me

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This looks very complicated and could be way easier I guess.

Comment: try  $('#clickme').click(function() {
   cond1.replaceWith(cloned_cond1).append('<option val="2">Opt2</option>');
   cond1 = $('#condition_value_1');
  });

Comment: The first code removes the attribute from the original element, not the cloned element, since you've chained it using [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) which returns the elements which were removed. Feel free to delete a question you're working on so that it doesn't gather answers you may not want.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ups, too late I was on the middle of the edit and didn't notice your comment, take a look now, I think it has a better explanation

Comment: @Anokrize better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `replaceWith` returns the *removed* element, not the new element. I suggest a different path:

```js
$(function() {
  var cond1 = $('#condition_value_1');
  var cloned_cond1 = cond1.clone().removeAttr('style');
  var cond1_select = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1" multiple="multiple"><option></option><option value="1">Opt1</option><option value="2">Opt2</option></select>';

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    cond1.replaceWith(cond1_select);
    $("#condition_value_1").select2({
      placeholder: 'Select choice'
    });
    cond1 = $("#condition_value_1");
  });

  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    if ($('#condition_value_1').hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible')) {
      $("#condition_value_1").select2('destroy');
    }

    $('#condition_value_1').replaceWith(cloned_cond1);
    cond1 = $('#condition_value_1');
  });
});
```

Note that I've removed the attribute from the clone before ever replacing anything; that way, you don't have to worry about it.

Note also in the `showme` click handler, we replace the HTML, then get a new hook to `$("#condition_value_1")`. That's because `cond1` is no longer in the DOM, since you've replaced it with the HTML in the first line.

Likewise, in the `clickme` click handler, you need to reset the value of `cond1` to match your new HTML.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, maybe you can remove your answer from this post (since I have flagged to an admin to be deleted and hopefully they will delete it) and add in [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592736/chained-method-calls-doesnt-work-on-original-nor-cloned-element)

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kknuuesq/10/)**.

I suggest to use a container then append the element you want to it, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var cond1 = $('#condition_value_1');
  var cloned_cond1 = cond1.clone();
  var cond1_select = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1" multiple="multiple"><option></option><option value="1">Opt1</option><option value="2">Opt2</option></select>';

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    $("#my-container").html(cond1_select);
    $("#condition_value_1").select2({placeholder: 'Select choice',width:'100%'});
  });

  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    if ($('#condition_value_1').hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible')) {
      $("#condition_value_1").select2('destroy');
    }
    $("#my-container").html(cloned_cond1);
    $("#condition_value_1").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<div id="my-container">
  <input type="text" id="condition_value_1" name="condition_1" style="display: none" />
</div>

<button id="showme">Make Select2</button>
<button id="clickme">Make Input</button>
```

Comment: This is not what I want, can you remove this answer and look again to the OP?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, maybe you can remove your answer from this post (since I have flagged to an admin to be deleted and hopefully they will delete it) and add in [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592736/chained-method-calls-doesnt-work-on-original-nor-cloned-element)