# Chained method calls doesn't work on original nor cloned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="condition_value_1" style="display: none" />    
<button id="showme">Make Select2</button>
<button id="clickme">Make Input</button>
```

Then take a look to the following jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var cond1 = $('#condition_value_1');
  var cloned_cond1 = cond1.clone();
  var cond1_select = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1" multiple="multiple"><option></option><option value="1">Opt1</option><option value="2">Opt2</option></select>';

  $('#showme').click(function() {
    cond1.removeAttr('style').replaceWith(cond1_select).select2({
      placeholder: 'Select choice'
    });

  });

  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    if ($('#condition_value_1').hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible')) {
      $("#condition_value_1").select2('destroy');
    }

    $('#condition_value_1').replaceWith(cloned_cond1).removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

You can try the code above [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/kknuuesq/4/).

Now as soon as you click on `#showme` you should remove the attr style, replace the original element with the given one and turn it into a Select2, the last part isn't working.

In the other side if you click on `#clickme` you should destroy the previous Select2 replace the `#condition_value_1` with the cloned element and remove the attr style because the cloned has that attribute but this is not working either.

The idea is to switch between elements and turn on/off properties on demand.

Maybe I am missing something here but I am not sure what. Could any help me here?

> Note: I've deleted my previous post to avoid confusions, apologies about that!

Comment: @Bergi, did you read my **NOTE**? I have flagged the post to an administrator because I want to remove it but I can't since it has a question so please remove your duplicate mark :) thx

Comment: If you have anything to add to your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40591987/edit)

Comment: Why would you want to remove it but keep a different question with exactly the same content?

Comment: Ok, I rely on this comment *Feel free to delete a question you're working on so that it doesn't gather answers you may not want* and now I am having problems, perfect! I flagged the other one, hopefully an administrator will remove it soon, this one is the correct answer

Comment: @Bergi because the previous one had a wrong answer and that was my bad, people was misunderstanding my needs and what I was looking for. During my edition someone answer with that comment so I open a new topic and flagged the other one to be deleted by an administrator since I can't.

Comment: Thanks, I see now, but you should at least have rolled-back your edit to the first question before posting that revision as a new question. As it stands, we have two identical questions with 4 posts answering it, right?

Comment: @Bergi yes, you're right but how can I do that? I don't have any problem to roll back it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `replaceWith()` returns the *original* jQuery object which now contains no elements as you replaced them.

In your logic structure this means you can't chain from those elements and need to start calls on the appended elements, like this:

```
var $cond1 = $('#condition_value_1');
var $cloned_cond1 = cond1.clone();
var cond1_select = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1" multiple="multiple"><option></option><option value="1">Opt1</option><option value="2">Opt2</option></select>';

$('#showme').click(function() {
    $cond1.replaceWith(cond1_select);
    $('#condition_value_1').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select choice'
    });
});

$('#clickme').click(function() {
    if ($('#condition_value_1').hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible')) {
        $("#condition_value_1").select2('destroy');
    }

    $('#condition_value_1').replaceWith($cloned_cond1);
    $cloned_cond1.removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do the following:

```
$("#div").replaceWith(".item2")
```

The object returned by the replaceWith method is the original set of objects. This because they might be replaced, but they still exists. Maybe not in the DOM but outside of it. Therefor you might want to do something else with it after replacement.

Therefor you need to make a seperate Javascript call where you select the right element and call the `removeAttr` and `select2` function.

> The .replaceWith() method, like most jQuery methods, returns the jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. However, **it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned**. This object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not the new element that has replaced it.

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/